# IntelliJ IDEA 17 - ASM Bytecode Outline isn't working

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-bytecode-asm

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.4 as my IDE. Recently I have found a plugin called *ASM Bytecode Outline* which is actually what I've dreamed of. I need such plugin so that I can convert Java code to ASM code or to bytecode easily.

I have installed the following plugin and restarted my IDE. Then I was expecting to be happy, however I was disappointed because the plugin seems not working:
[image: Here's the picture of what I see]

Simply nothing.

I have tried the following:

- Recompile and rebuild the project.
- Restart IntelliJ.
- Reinstall the plugin.
- Restart my PC.

However, as you see me asking here now, you can guess that none from what I tried has worked, sadly. I clearly understand that the plugin might be pretty old and was not updated for years, but I still need at least something similar that can convert Java code to ASM-ready code, like:

[image: on this picture].

Is there a way I can solve this, or is there any other similar solution (not required to be an IntelliJ plugin) for what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated the plugin and now it works fine with newer versions of Intellij IDEA.
You can download it from here: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10302-asm-bytecode-viewer

The source code can be found in here: https://github.com/elitegit/asm-intellij-plugin
It includes the latest version of ASM library as well.

You can use the plugin in 3 different ways:

1. Right click somewhere inside the code editor and choose "Show
   Bytecode Viewer"
2. In the "Code" menu, choose "Show Bytecode
   Viewer"
3. Right click on the java file in the Project window and
   choose "Show Bytecode Viewer"

You can find the setting inside Settings => Tools => "Show Bytecode Viewer"

Answer (score 0):

`ASM Bytecode Outline` isn't compatible with IntelliJ 2017.1.4.  The last time this plugin was updated was September 2015.  [Here's a link to the plugin page](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5918-asm-bytecode-outline) on JetBrains' website: you can see that it stopped being compatible in IntelliJ 14.

**Alternative**

A *built-in bytecode viewer* has been available in IntelliJ for a while.  Use the menu `View -> Show Bytecode` to view the bytecode for one of your classes.  See [this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/intellij-idea-pro-tips.html) for more details.

Comment: I've actually mentioned that I need a tool to transform Java code to ASMfied code so I can easily create classes and methods with ASM (like you see on the 2nd picture attached to my question post), not just the tool that only shows the bytecode itself.

Comment: @HopeIsNope: but do you need it so often that it has to be a panel within your IDE? If you are using ASM, you have it in your class path and may invoke `ASMifier` from your code or from the command line whenever needed…

Comment: My question mentions that it isn't required it to be an IntelliJ addition and external software is also appreciated.